# Unable to retreive JSON list from postgres using JAVA

Tags: java, postgresql

I get error when trying to retrieve JSON array from Postgres

Here is my model:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

@Entity

@TypeDefs({
        @TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JSONBUserType.class, parameters = {
                @Parameter(name = JSONBUserType.CLASS, value = "com.ats.modules.candidate.model.Skills") }),
        @TypeDef(name = "jsonbexp", typeClass = JSONBUserType.class, parameters = {
                @Parameter(name = JSONBUserType.CLASS, value = "com.ats.modules.candidate.model.Experience") }),
        @TypeDef(name = "jsonbedu", typeClass = JSONBUserType.class, parameters = {
                @Parameter(name = JSONBUserType.CLASS, value = "com.ats.modules.candidate.model.Education") }) })

@Table(name = "candidate")

public class Candidate implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "bigserial")
    private Long id;
    // private Long userid;
    // private String salutation;
    private String firstname;
    // private String middlename;
    private String lastname;
    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    // private Skills skills;
    @JsonProperty("skills")
    public List<Skills> skills;
    @Type(type = "jsonbexp")
    private Experience experience;
    @Type(type = "jsonbedu")
    private Education education;



    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }


    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public Experience getExperience() {
        return experience;
    }

    @JsonProperty("skills")
    public List<Skills> getSkills() {
        return skills;
    }

    public void setSkills(List<Skills> skills) {
        this.skills = skills;
    }

    public void setExperience(Experience experience) {
        this.experience = experience;
    }

    public Education getEducation() {
        return education;
    }

    public void setEducation(Education education) {
        this.education = education;
    }


}
```

Error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of com.ats.modules.candidate.model.Skills out of START_ARRAY token  at [Source: [{"skill": "id", "version": "STRING_TYPE", "lastused": null, "yrsworked": null, "proficiency": "1"}, {"skill": "id2", "version": "STRING_TYPE", "lastused": null, "yrsworked": null, "proficiency": "12"}]; line: 1, column: 1]   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:270)
```

My JSON that get saved:

```
{
   "firstname":"rishs",
   "lastname":"rajan",

 "skills":  [
                {
                    "skill": "id",
                    "proficiency": "1",
                    "version": "STRING_TYPE"
                },
                {
                    "skill": "id2",
                    "proficiency": "12",
                    "version": "STRING_TYPE"
                }
            ]
}
```

I am able to save data in postgres but unable to retrieve. When I try to retrieve I get the de-serialize mapping error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to parse `firstname` and `lastname` with [JsonObject](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html) and you need to parse `skills` with [JsonArray](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonArray.html), then you will be able to access them.

you can use org.json library:

```
import org.json.*;

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(" .... ");
String pageName = obj.getJSONObject("pageInfo").getString("pageName");

JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("posts");
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++)
{
    String post_id = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("post_id");
    ......
}
```

Comment: Do u have a sample code for it ...where exactly should i put my parse code